# How to write Arquillian test classes for OSGi (integration) testing?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, jboss-arquillian

I am currently investigating how best to test our project wittern in Apache Camel and running on Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated extension for OSGi - please have a look at the docs on GitHub https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-osgi